# Check if MySQL Database Exists with VB

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

Hi Guys i am trying to write some code to check if a MySQL Database exists and then write a line in the console if it exists or not.

i did some googling and found this code but i get a syntax error, if anyone knows how to do this it would be greatly appreciated.

```
Function DoesDBExist(DBConnectionString As String, Logger As String)

    Dim exists As Byte = 0

    Dim conn As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection(DBConnectionString)

    Dim cmd As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand("SELECT case when exists " & _
       "(select 1 from sys.Databases SELECT case when exists " & _
       "(select 1 from sys.Databases where Name = @DbName) " & _
       "then 1 else 0 end as DbExists", conn)

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DbName", "MDLUpdate")

    conn.Open()

    exists = CByte(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
    Console.WriteLine(exists)
    Console.ReadKey()
    conn.Close()

    Return CBool(exists)

End Function
```

Please Forgive me for the tags i am not 100% sure with which ones to use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code could be something like this

```
Function DoesDBExist(DBConnectionString As String, Logger As String) as Boolean

    Dim conn As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection(DBConnectionString)
    Dim cmd As MySqlCommand = new MySqlCommand("SELECT IF(EXISTS (SELECT SCHEMA_NAME " & _
        "FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA WHERE SCHEMA_NAME = @DbName), 'Y','N')", conn) 
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DbName", "MDLUpdate")
    conn.Open()
    Dim exists As String = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString()
    Console.WriteLine(exists)
    conn.Close()
    Return IF(exists = "Y", True, False)

End Function
```